# How to move two boxes at multiplayer if input buffer reads only one character at a time?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bios

I am writing an assembly program for two boxes moving at the same time and I want the two players on the same pc to move with each other. How to do that with int 16h/1 and int 16h/0

I tried it with int 16 but could not find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you're describing was solved in [Making a pong game in assembly, how do I get an input of multiple keystrokes at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67386755/making-a-pong-game-in-assembly-how-do-i-get-an-input-of-multiple-keystrokes-at/67431848?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C23.6713#67431848).

Of course, you'll have to swap my *colored* boxes for your *moving* boxes, but the underlying methods are the same. Good luck and ask another question if implementing poses some specific trouble(s).

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try it insha2 Allah.