# assembler 16 bit keyboard input interrupt handler (int 9h) code has an invalid instruction

Tags: assembly, interrupt, keyboard-events, turbo-pascal

I'm writing a 2 dimensional game for training an AI to play the game (kind of reinforcement learning). Before training the neural network I want to let the user generate the needed input patterns by capturing all key events when playing the game. It is important that both the keys pressed and the keys released are detected and also when pressing multiple keys (for example right arrow and Ctrl at the same time). I found some piece of code from Leo Ono on YouTube that seemed usefull to me at first. Unfortunately the assembler code has errors when running the game for more than 5 minutes. When I turn the keyboard input interrupt handler off the game works fine. The video memory is corrupted and the game halts after 5 minutes.
Maybe the title of this site is appropriate for the problem because I suspect that the stack memory is overflowing but I have no idea how to increase the stack memory in the assembler code (NASM 16 bit).

I tried the following code (NASM 16 bit):

```
    
        bits 16

        global _install_key_handler
        global _uninstall_key_handler
        global _is_key_pressed
        
segment _TEXT public class=CODE

  _install_key_handler:
        PUSH ES
        CLI
        MOV AX,0
        MOV ES,AX
        MOV AX,[ES:4*9+2]
        MOV [DS:int9_original_segment],AX
        MOV AX,[ES:4*9]
        MOV [DS:int9_original_offset],AX
        MOV AX,CS
        MOV WORD [ES:4*9+2],AX
        MOV WORD [ES:4*9],key_handler
        STI
        POP ES
        RETF

  _uninstall_key_handler:
        PUSH ES
        MOV AX,0
        MOV ES,AX
        CLI
        MOV AX,[int9_original_offset]
        MOV [ES:4*9],AX
        MOV AX,[int9_original_segment]
        MOV [ES:4*9+2],AX
        STI
        POP ES
        RETF

  _is_key_pressed:
        PUSH BP
        MOV BP,SP
        MOV BX,[BP+6]
        MOV AL,[key_pressed+BX]
        MOV AH,0
        POP BP
        RETF

  key_handler:
        PUSH ES
        PUSH AX
        PUSH BX
        MOV AX,_DATA
        MOV ES,AX
        IN AL,60h
        CMP AL,0E0h
        JZ .ignore
        MOV AH,0
        MOV BX,AX
        AND BL,01111111b
        AND AL,10000000b
        CMP AL,10000000b
        JZ .key_released
    .key_pressed:
        MOV BYTE [ES:key_pressed+BX],1
        JMP .ignore
    .key_released:
        MOV BYTE [ES:key_pressed+BX],0
    .ignore:
        MOV AL,20h
        OUT 20h,al
        POP BX
        POP AX
        POP ES
        IRET

section _DATA public class=DATA
  int9_original_offset DW 0
  int9_original_segment DW 0

  key_pressed times 256 DB 0
```

I tried to push and pop additional registers (AX and BX) at _is_key_pressed and install/uninstall but that didn't help. I tried to increase the stack memory in Turbo Pascal 16 bit which contains the main source code but this didn't help either. I tried the i8086 cross compiler of free pascal instead of Turbo Pascal but the game only runs without the keyboard input interupt handler code (with the NASM code I get an 'invalid instruction' error.)
Is there someone who knows alternative low level keyboard input interrupt handler code with the INT 09h instruction on the 60h keyboard port? I searched extensively on Google but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Note that all the functions end with a `RETF` so make sure you use a far call when invoking them. The handler seems fine, if that does not fix the problem then it is likely elsewhere just maybe triggered by actually having a way to detect key presses.

Comment: Thanks. I adjusted the unit with far calls. Should it be like the following: unit TKeyInt4;

interface

const
     ESC1 = Chr(10);
     LARR1 = Chr(75);
     RARR1 = Chr(77);
     CTRL1 = Chr(29);
     ALT1 = Chr(56);
     ESC2 = Chr(1);

procedure _install_key_handler; far;

procedure _uninstall_key_handler; far;

function _is_key_pressed(Code : Char) : Byte; far;

implementation

procedure _install_key_handler; external;

procedure _uninstall_key_handler; external;

function _is_key_pressed(Code : Char) : Byte; external;

{$L keyboard.obj}


end.

Comment: Not a fix to the bug, but `key_pressed times 256 DB 0` would suffice to use `times 128`

Comment: My demo program in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67386755/making-a-pong-game-in-assembly-how-do-i-get-an-input-of-multiple-keystrokes-at/67431848#67431848 uses the same technique and that program works fine.

Comment: Also since you seem to be calling this from pascal, make sure you follow the calling convention. I don't remember if you are allowed to change `bx` for example. Furthermore none of the functions set `ds` so `_is_key_pressed` might not be looking in the same array that `key_handler` is writing into (but this should not cause the problem you describe).

Comment: @Jester, I believe ax, bx, cx, dx and the es registers are considered volatile.

Comment: I saw that TP has difficulty with the IRET operation. So I'm looking for an alternative to exit the procedure.

Comment: I need this code from the YouTube video because it works with an interrupt procedure. Without an interrupt procedure additional keys are not detected. For example when you press arrow right shortly after Ctrl the game character keeps jumping after releasing the Ctrl key. I'm convinced that the problem can be solved by cleaning up something in the stack, but I don't know exactly what. Maybe someone can help? Thanks.

Comment: I found old code for Turbo Pascal from 1996 for keyboard interrupt handling partial in assembler. My 2d game works now just fine. https://gist.github.com/Fortyseven/4f5a4f3c4750a00d311f